# @Cacheable with timeout/ hystrix spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-annotations, hystrix

I am using @Cachebale for caching request responses.

```
@Cacheable
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod = "myFallBackResponse" )
public Response call(Request request) {}
```

As you can see in above code , I have used netflix-hystix for setting a timeout to this method call .

But when this call goes to cache , then the hystrix timeout is completely ignored.

Is there any way to associate timeout with @Cacheable , with or without hystrix?

Comment: what do you meant by this "But when this call goes to cache , then the hystrix timeout is completely ignored". when the call doesnt go inside the method, it goes to cache. why wud it timeout when it goes to cache, from where you can get the result immediately

Comment: in non-ideal situation when my remote cache(redis) is down , it first goes to redis, where it fails to connect to redis, then goes to make the method call. I want to set a timeout for the entire trip to redis to actual method call

Answer (score 0):

I am still researching this but...
AFAIK each annotation creates it's own Aspect (AOP) pointcut. And the order of them is not guaranteed unless explicitly defined (which I am not 100% sure you can do with these annotations).
Hystrix (Javanica) has it's own cache mechanism, the underlying cache might be same (ehcache) library but it has it's own commands controlling caching: cache name,key, evict.
I think the solution is to remove cacheable annotation and using Hystrix (Javanica) own Hystrix cache annotation.